# Bloc initial state is not emitted anymore

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have a bloc that listens to another bloc. After updating the `flutter_bloc` package to `version 6.0.2`, the listener won't call anymore in the initial state.

```dart
class BlocA extends Bloc {
  final BlocB blocB = ...;

  ...
  blocA.blocB.listen((state) {
    DO SOMTTHING...
  });
  ...
}
```

I found this solution:

```dart
class BlocB extends Bloc<..., ...> with BehaviorSubjectBloc {
  ...
}

mixin BehaviorSubjectBloc<TEvent, TState> on Bloc<TEvent, TState> {
  @override
  StreamSubscription<TState> listen(
    void Function(TState state) onData, {
    Function onError,
    void Function() onDone,
    bool cancelOnError,
  }) {
    onData(this.state);

    return super.listen(
      onData,
      onError: onError,
      onDone: onDone,
      cancelOnError: cancelOnError,
    );
  }
}
```

I wonder if is there any better solution?

Comment: What do you need to accomplish ? Isn't a solution for you to access the blocA.state from BlocB constructor and treat this as a particular case ?

This is a known breaking change (sadly) which was documented on the (Migration page](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=%e2%9d%97bloc-does-not-emit-last-state-on-subscription).

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue about it in the flutter_bloc repo:

 https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1641

The issue is on the todo list.

You may fix your yaml to force the previous version, using single quotes and removing the "^" or any other symbols. Delete your `~/.pub-cache/...` folder and your `pubspec.lock` file, run `flutter packages get` again and be happy.

Note that the pub-cache folder is shared among all your projects, so you may try to delete only the specific package inside it.

You can investigate transitive dependencies using `flutter packages pub deps` to see the `flutter_bloc` dependencies and delete them too.

Comment: Just a completion to your answer: this breaking changes are stated in the [Migration to 6.0.0 Documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=%e2%9d%97bloc-does-not-emit-last-state-on-subscription).